# Creating new text file using date and time as text file name

Tags: java

Can someone show me an example code of how to create new text file using date and time as text file name. Please show also how to save that new text file in a specific folder path in computer. I try this but its not working

```
File f = new File("D://FILEPATH//Clear.DAT");
String fileName = f.getName();
fileName = fileName+new java.util.Date() +".DAT";
System.out.println(fileName);
```

Comment: I already put the segment of code. Can you have a look? tq

Answer (score 3):

First, get the date and time as a `String` formatted correctly. You can use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). And you can use the [`File(File, String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File-java.io.File-java.lang.String-) constructor to give your `File` the correct folder. Then you might use a [`PrintStream(File)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#PrintStream-java.io.File-) to `print` something. And a [`try-with-resources` Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to clean-up. Finally, you could put that all together into something like

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
File folder = new File("D://FILEPATH");
File f = new File(folder, String.format("Clear-%s.TXT", df.format(new Date())));
try (PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(f) {
    ps.println("Hello, File!");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I try this but its not working. No file save in folder

Comment: You need to write something to the `File` (it represents an abstract path). You could use a [`PrintStream(File)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#PrintStream-java.io.File-) and `print` something. Edited to give an example.

Comment: Thank you. Its work. This new file is save in DAT format. Since DAT file cannot be opened directly from the file. Is it a way to save this file in ".txt" format ?

Comment: @Belle Yes. You can use whatever extension you like.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create file name with date from the very beginning.
Plus, it would be great to choose date and time format that you are going to use.

Answer (score 0):

```
Date date = new Date() ;
SimpleDateFormat dateObject = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss") ;
File yourTextFile = new File(dateObject.format(date) + ".tsv") ;
BufferedWriter result = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(yourTextFile));
result.write("Writing content");
out.close();
```

Try with above code. It will create a file with the current date and time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more way i used with Java8

```
String dateTime= DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss").format(ZonedDateTime.now());
String fileName = String.format("Clear-%s.DAT", dateTime);
Path filePath = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("D://FILEPATH//", fileName);
Files.createFile(filePath);
```